# C# Сортировка одного столбца (первого) в двумерном массиве (2 столбца) с перестановкой элементов во втором столбце в соотвествии с первым столбцом

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка

Задан такой массив:

int [,] sortNums = new int [3, 2]; // к примеру 
Там может быть что-то вроде 
{ 3, 0}, { 2, 1}, { 4, 2}

3  0

2  1

4  2

Первый столбец сортируем, предположим, по возрастанию и получаем 2, 3, 4

В итоге получаем такой вид:

2  1

3  0

4  2

Вопрос в итоге такой:
Есть какой-то супер метод, который отсортирует мне в такой вид, если я поставлю условие? Может linq или ещё что-то...

В Java нашлась реализация:
Arrays.Sort(sortNums, Comparator.comparing((int[] arr)-> arr [0])); 
Но ничего похожего для C# не нашлось.

Answer (score 0):

Так можно отсортировать только массив массивов:

```
int[][] data = new int[3][];
data[0] = new int[] { 3, 0 };
data[1] = new int[] { 2, 1 };
data[2] = new int[] { 4, 2 };

Array.Sort(data, (a, b) => a[0].CompareTo(b[0]));

foreach (int[] row in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", row));
}

// 2 1
// 3 0
// 4 2
```

С матрицей придется немного повозиться [ideone](https://ideone.com/J2isuq):

```
class Array2DComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        int[] x = (int[])a;
        int[] y = (int[])b;

        for (int index = 0; index < x.Length; index++)
        {
            if (x[index] > y[index])
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if (x[index] < y[index])
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

static int[][] ConvertToJagged(int[,] rectangularArray)
{
    int rows = rectangularArray.GetLength(0);
    int cols = rectangularArray.GetLength(1);

    int[][] jaggedArray = new int[rows][];

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        int[] item = new int[cols];

        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            item[col] = rectangularArray[row, col];
        }

        jaggedArray[row] = item;
    }

    return jaggedArray;

    // либо в одну строчку с помощью LINQ
    // return Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0)).Select(row => Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(1)).Select(col => array[row, col]).ToArray()).ToArray();
}

static int[,] ConvertToRectangular(int[][] jaggedArray)
{
    int rows = jaggedArray.Length;
    int cols = jaggedArray[0].Length;

    int[,] rectangularArray = new int[rows, cols];

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            rectangularArray[row, col] = jaggedArray[row][col];
        }
    }

    return rectangularArray;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] rectangularArray = { 
        { 3, 0, 2 }, 
        { 3, 0, 1 }, 
        { 2, 1, 5 }, 
        { 3, 1, 6 }, 
        { 4, 2, 8 }
    };

    // Преобразовываем в "зубчатый" массив
    int[][] jaggedArray = ConvertToJagged(rectangularArray);

    // Сортируем по возрастанию элементов
    Array.Sort(jaggedArray, new Array2DComparer());

    foreach (var item in jaggedArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", item));
    }

    // Преобразовываем обратно в "матричный" массив
    rectangularArray = ConvertToRectangular(jaggedArray);
}

// 2 1 5
// 3 0 1
// 3 0 2
// 3 1 6
// 4 2 8
```

Comment: А если все таки int[ , ]?

Comment: @МарияБорцова немного сложнее, в одну строчку не получится, добавил код

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю более компактное решение задачи:

```
static int[,] Sort2DArray(int[,] arr)
{
    // Создаем временный jagged-массив для хранения данных исходного прямоугольного массива
    int[][] tmpArr = arr.Cast<int>().Chunk(arr.GetLength(1)).ToArray();

    // Сортируем временный массив по значению первого элемента строки по возрастанию
    // (либо столбца с первыми неравными элементами)
    Array.Sort(tmpArr, (x, y) => x.Zip(y, (a, b) => a - b).FirstOrDefault(x => x != 0));

    // Создаем прямоугольный массив для записи в него отсортированных данных 
    int[,] res = new int[arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1)];

    // Заполняем массив полученными данными
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            res[i, j] = tmpArr[i][j];

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

С матрицей возиться не нужно. Зачем это всё представлено в виде двумерного массива? Представим сие как структуру из пары интов. И тогда получится одномерный массив из этих структур.

```
псевдокод
{3, 0}, {2, 1}, {4, 2} = структура{3, 0}, структура{2, 1}, структура{4, 2}
```

У структуры нужно определить компаратор. И затем сортировать массив структур.

```
public struct Struct : System.IComparable<Struct>
{
    public readonly int _0, _1;

    public Struct(int _0, int _1)
    {
        this._0 = _0;
        this._1 = _1;
    }
    public int CompareTo(Struct y)
    {
        return _0.CompareTo(y._0);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", _0, _1);
    }
}

public static class Main
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        Struct[] structs = new Struct[3]
        {
            new Struct(3, 0),
            new Struct(2, 1),
            new Struct(4, 2),
        };

        System.Array.Sort<Struct>(structs);

        foreach (var item in structs)
            System.Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

// out:
// 2 1
// 3 0
// 4 2
```

Понятное дело, что возникает некоторая проблема. Заключается она в том, что нужно "перегнать" двумерный массив в одномерный массив структур. Но, во-первых, двумерный массив вообще пользовать не нужно. А во-вторых, даже если и есть крайняя необходимость пользования двумерного массива, то существуют опасные способы перекаста массивов в массивы. Где данные массивов, **не** **меняются**, однако же меняется тип массива. Т.е. дополнительные массивы не создаются вовсе, а меняется (подменяется) тип.

Выглядит это примерно следующим образом:

```
// Читаем например байты откуда то
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("array.bin");

int[,] ints = null;

// Перекастовываем байты да хоть во что
using (Sys.Memory mem = (Sys.Memory)bytes)
{
    if (mem.Undefined) throw new Sys.Memory.CastException();

    // Перекаст за O(1)
    // одномерный массив байт стал двумерным массивом интов
    ints = mem.AsArray<int[,]>(2);

    // Ещё перекаст за O(1), структура определена выше
    // двумерный массив интов стал одномерным массивом из Struct
    Struct[] structs = mem.AsArray<Struct[]>();

    // Сортируем
    System.Array.Sort<Struct>(structs);

    // Перекастовываем отсортированное в нужное за O(1)
    // Получаем отсортированный двумерный массив без оверхеда
    // одномерный массив из Struct стал двумерным массивом интов
    ints = mem.AsArray<int[,]>(2);

    // Перекасты
    // Перекасты...
    // Сколько хотите - столько и перекастовывайте
}
```

Реализуется это всё специфическими небезопасными способами, и обычно это всё имеет собственные реализации. И да, это противоречит принципам дот.нета - это когда всё строго типизировано. Но те кто привыкли к сишняку - проблем с небезопасной типизацией - не имеют, и перекастовывают "на лету" всё что нужно - в любое иное нужное. По понятным причинам никакие реализации небезопасных способов перекаста приводиться не будут (более менее внятная реализация перекаста массивов - это ~30 тыщ строк). И так как автор спрашивал про "супер-методы" - то они есть. Они существуют.

П.С.: Некоторые пояснения по поводу того, а почему не стоит пользовать двумерный массив на интах. Суть тут в том, что сортировка такого массива в принципе возможна, но она по определению пойдёт на интах. И это плохо. Сортировать нужно более крупными кусками, например лонгами, т.е. в сортировщик должны залетать лонги а не инты. И тогда сортировщик будет копировать лонги (инт+инт=лонг), и это быстрее чем возиться с интами. Сортировка подразумевает множественное копирование, но копировать по инту - это и есть путь в никуда. А копировать структуры из интов - это сильно лучше, это быстрее. Потому что такие структуры будут копироваться за такт. Или инт копируется за такт, или же два инта (структурой) копируется за такт. Понятное дело, что держать два инта в структуре выгодней, чем держать инты в двумерном массиве.

Comment: Какая-то графомания. К чему всё это? Вопрос совсем о другом

Comment: Графомания в чём? В пяти строчках кода? Структура с компаратором предельно простая. И сортировка массива этих структур - это одна строка. Вы путаете графоманию с чем то другим. Это когда на предельно простые операции пишут код из 100 строчек вместо пяти.

Comment: Ну давайте обратимся к словарю Ожегова. "Графомания - Болезненное пристрастие к сочинительству". Судя по вашим ответам на аккаунте так оно и есть. Причем тут компараторы? Причем структуры? Причем тут файлы bin? Причем тут перекасты из одного типа в другой? Вопрос был о том, как сортировать двумерный массив, а вы захардкодили структуру с двумя полями хотя в вопросе матрица 3х2 была примером. Весь ваш ответ можно было сократить до 1 строчки кода и всё. Объяснение как там инты хранятся и что выгоднее не относятся к теме вопроса. Если хотите об этом рассказать - сами создайте вопрос и ответьте

Comment: Графоманию прекратите. У вас слишком много вопросов. Вместо кучи вопросов - написали бы кучу ответов. И всё. В коде. И объяснения. И объяснения - это три абзаца. Гражданин, программирование - это данные и алгоритмы над ними, и это в словаре Ожегова не написано. Если хотите писать (вы что. графоман?) - ну пишите. Только как ваша писанина имеет отношение к делу? Причём здесь Ожегов? Вы пьяны? "Весь ваш ответ можно было сократить до 1 строчки кода и всё." - СОКРАТИТЕ. Вам кто мешает то? Заодно сократите код на 100 строк, тут где то кто то выдал полотно на сотню, вы и там проведите все сокращения.